# PHP session conflict

Tags: php

I'm getting a conflict with these 2 sections of code:
first one to validate that the log in session is in the database tab

```
include "../scripts/connectpage.php"; 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE id='$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");

$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
if ($existCount == 0) { 
 echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database.";
 exit();
```

and this one that list all content of another tab

```
$product_list ="";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_added DESC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($productCount > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
    $product_list .=  and so on.........
```

I can log in to the page and it seems fine but I if I refresh it or execute any other stuff on the page, the first code don't validate anymore with the database and I get the echo. If I remove either of the codes they both work fine independently.

Comment: If it is Session related question than why can't I see the SESSION variable in your code?

Comment: You should use `mysqli` functions instead of `mysql`.

Comment: Post the whole script.

Comment: What happens if you echo your `$name` an `$password` variables?

Comment: why don't you store the $existCount result into a $_SESSION variable once the user has been validated?

Comment: I'm looking forward to use the mysqli so when I echo $name and $pass I do get the right name and pass. I know I should use a more secure login... storing the $existCount into a $_SESSION variable might be a good idea. Can I store it as a random secure variable?

Comment: hmmmm when I echo the $ID, $name, $pass variables on the index page name, pass and ID are good ID=1   I refresh it or get back to it and it stays good.   On that problematic page from original post with the same validation code  gives me name, pass good but ID=3  wich doesn't match the db.   If I remove the second part of code from the original post for product listing, the ID stays 1 ....  why?? hehehe   Thanks guys for contributing to my PHP learning process

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because when you refresh the page, variables:

`$managerID`, `$manager`,`$password`

are not visible anymore on the page.

How you assign value to those variables, through `get` or `post` request ?

Comment: I assign them through $_post

Comment: The login page that post the variables saved as $_SESSION  leads to the main page with the exact same validation code. This page I can refresh or get back to it as I want.  But if I load that problematic page and refresh, it doesn't validate any of them anymore  and it works fine if I remove that second code from the original post.